# ReadOuterXml() adds format attribute tag to my data

Tags: .net, xmltextreader

I have the classic XmlTextReader problem where I need to process the tag as a whole as well as child within it. So what I did was this:

```
AllRD = New XmlTextReader(New StringReader(XMLString.Trim())) ' an entire file
Do While AllRD.Read()
   ... loop until I find the tag I'm interested in ...
   CellXML = AllRD.ReadOuterXml()
   CellRD = New XmlTextReader(New StringReader(CellXML.Trim()))
   Do While CellRD.Read()
      ... stuff ...
```

This lets me parse the inner XML with `Read` and still access the entire tag when I get to the bottom of the loop. So now I feed it this string:

```
<c r="A1" s="2" t="s"><v>0</v></c>
```

and when I examine `CellXML` I get this:

```
<c r="A1" s="2" t="s" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><v>0</v></c>
```

Anyone know how to make that new `xmlns` go away?

Answer (score 0):

Well after a lot more Googling I returned back to SO to find the solution:

[How to remove xmlns attribute with .NET XML API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76424/how-to-remove-xmlns-attribute-with-net-xml-api)

The trick is to do:

```
AllRD = New XmlTextReader(New StringReader(XMLString.Trim()))
AllRD.Namespace = false
```

Not entirely obvious, and frankly, this should be default behavior IMHO.